# How to do a Join and a Loop corectly using R

Tags: r, loops, join, apply, cbind

I have two sets of data that have a column `mean_wage` in common, but they are described differently.

First one as 1 (wage), 2, 2.4 ... and the other one as 1256.7 dollars. Because I'm looking at different years I have to make a wage adjustment, so I find it easier to work with salaries this way (1256.7).

How can I create a new column that loops the wage?

Example:

```
Data_Frame <- data.frame (
  Training = c("Enginner", "Lawyer", "Welder", "Teacher", "Police Officer","Street Sweepers"),
  Mean_Wage = c(4, 6, 1.2,2,2,1),
  Scholarity_years = c("Undergraduate", "MSc", "High School", "Undergraduate", "High School","High School")
)

# Print the data frame
Data_Frame

Data_Frame2 <- data.frame (Mean_Wage = (1256.7))

Data_Frame2
```

I would like to create a new column that contain the function 1256.7 * 1, 2, 3, 2.4...

I tried to bind cols in my original file and got this error

> Can't recycle `..1` (size 12) to match `..2` (size 231456...
> Backtrace:
>
> 1. dplyr::bind_cols(Data_Frame, Data_Frame2)
> 2. vctrs::stop_incompatible_size(...)
> 3. vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
> 4. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)

Comment: Do you mean `transform(Data_Frame, Mean_Wage=Mean_Wage*1256.7)`?

Comment: Exactly. Why i did not thought that? Thank you.

Comment: Next time you will! ;)